# Helm Chart Versions

Tags: continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to set up a development and build process for Helm charts. I have kept the Helm Chart template files, values files etc in GitLab in a project (we are having the helm charts in the different project from image build projects). I can use Jenkins to package the helm chart and push it to the repository. But we want to keep the helm chart version to be in snapshot until it is tested on dev environment and then release it with a proper release version.

Problem: The chart version is in Chart.yaml but how it will be auto updated in GitLab when I am ready to make a release. So I can use helm package command with version flag and it will create the tar.gz with release version but I want to read that version from Chart.yaml , trim the snapshot bit and once package and push is done, update Charts.yaml with next snapshot (without manual intervention). Same as what we are do for with maven release in jenkins.

Can anyone guide me if there are other better approaches to work with Helm Charts releases?

Thanks.